# Failed Checkin in TFS: could not find file

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget

> Multiple errors occurred during the operation, the first of which is displayed below. A full error list is available in the Output Window.
>
> Could not find file
> 'C:\tfs\Locabal\Locabal\packages\ImageResizer.FluentExtensions.1.0.0.4\ImageResizer.FluentExtensions.1.0.0.4.nupkg'.

I can't find any references to ImageResizer. It's long since been removed and there are no references or nuget references to it. I ran this command and the project ImageManager has also been removed, it is not in the solution and I removed it via the VS IDE.

> PS C:\tfs\Locabal> dir -Recurse *.config | Select-String
> 'ImageResizer'
>
> Locabal\ImageManager\packages.config:6:  
> Locabal\ImageManager\packages.config:7:  
> Locabal\ImageManager\packages.config:8:   Locabal\ImageManager\packages.config:9:   Locabal\ImageManager\packages.config:10:

Comment: I don't know if this counts as an acceptable solution, but I removed the packages folder from source control and it fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Third party libraries should checked-in one time at the beginning and you would never checked-out them for edit, since there is no edit about them, so they must be exist on a folder outside the project main folder so if you click on the whole project to check-out for edit, it will not affected, I recommended you to to have a look on the folder structured on the TFS and how we should put our third party dlls and frameworks.

```
$MyTeamProject1
         /Main                                                              Can contain solution (.sln) files    
                /Source
                            /MyApp1                                         Contains MyApp1.sln file
                                        /Source                             Contain folder for all source
                                                    /ClassLibrary1          Contains ClassLibrary1.csproj
                                                    /MyApp1Web              Contains Default.aspx
                                        /UnitTests                          Container folder for unit tests
                                                    /ClassLibrary1Tests     Contains test project and code
                                                    /MyApp1WebTests         Contains test project and code
                            /SharedBinaries                                 Shared binaries e.g. libraries
                            /SharedSource                                   Shared source code           
                /Docs                                                       Contains product documentation
                /Tests                                                      Container for tests
                            /FunctionalTests
                            /PerformanceTests
                            /SecurityTests /
```

More info:

[Chapter 4 – Structuring Projects and Solutions in Team Foundation Source Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668954.aspx)